# Oozie cant able to find JDBC drivers in Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie, sqoop2

Refrence to the previously asked question  Oozie + Sqoop: JDBC Driver Jar Location 1 
but not able to find jar in HDFS /user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop location.

I have also tried to put driver jars at my workFlow app Lib. Still Drivers not found error occure.

Comment: Are you running hadoop cluster in psuedo mode or distributed mode ?

Comment: copy thse driver jars into that location of hdfs if not present. only then oozie can run sqoop using these jars. oozie will not look up for jars in hadoop home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all lib files like jdbc drivers, etc in the oozie share lib folder inside sqoop folder .

This should resolve your issue.

To check the library files invoked/used by the job , go to the job tracker for the corresponding job and in syslogs you will see which all jars has been used.

Comment: by adding jdbc driver jars in the workflow lib it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The exact problem was the single coats "'". Because of single coats oozie take it as a single string. But it was working fine when I was using it in the Sqoop command.

.................  --driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServer...................

instead of.

..................  --driver 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServer'................